# How to get Class Model name from ManyToManyField in Django

Tags: django, many-to-many, metamodel

I need to get Class Model name from #django.db.models.fields.related.ManyToManyField object.For example:

```
class Source(models.Model):
    groups = models.ManyToManyField(Group)

    def generated_sql(self):
        print [f.name for f in self._meta.many_to_many]

        #tehere I need to get Class Model name for f, in this case will be: Group
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
groups = models.ManyToManyField(Group)

def generated_sql(self):
    print [(f.name, f.related.parent_model) for f in self._meta.many_to_many]
```

iPython ftw